# Run-time error '-2145320854 (8021006a)': Automation error, while accessing image properties

Tags: vba, wia

I am trying to find duplicate images, following a simple (*and rudimentary*) logic. If two images were taken at the same exact time, and are identical in size, chances are they must be duplicates.

Here's my relevant code

```
Set ImgFile = New WIA.ImageFile
ImgFile.LoadFile (fullFilePath)
If (Right(fullFilePath, 3) = "JPG") Then
  ImgFile.LoadFile (fullFilePath)
  pictureTaken = ImgFile.Properties("DateTime")
End If
```

It extracts the "picture taken" property accurately for most images, but once in a while it encounters an image that does not have that property set. That's when it throws the runtime error.

I'll take any advice about the specific error message (*or a better approach to the problem I am trying to solve*).

Comment: Can't you just use a `FileSystemObject` to check the date? I am not familiar with `WIA` - Read this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/datecreated-property - Based on the Tag description, WIA seems to be meant for Windows Me and Windows XP?

Comment: Also, you do not need parenthesis to call a VBA subroutine, you only need them to call functions, so these lines should be: `ImgFile.LoadFile fullFilePath`

Comment: FileSystemObject gives me the date when the file was created on the PC. I instead want the date when the picture was originally taken by the camera, for my logic to work. That info is saved as a property within JPG (and presumably other formats), right along with things like GPS coordinates etc.

Comment: ah, i see. in that case my suggestion will not help.